# Adding Diagnostic Setting to an Azure FunctionApp using Azure Resource Manager library for .NET

Tags: c#, azure, deployment

I am using the [C# Azure Resource Manager library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resource-manager?view=azure-dotnet) to create Azure resources.

I have created a function using the following code:

```
WebSiteData webSiteData = new WebSiteData(location);
webSiteData.Kind = "functionapp";
var funcResponse = await resourceGroup.GetWebSites().CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, functionName, webSiteData);
var funcResource = funcResponse.Value;
```

I want to configure the FunctionApp to log to a Log Analytics Workspace using the Diagnostic Setting. However I can't see how to do this with the Azure.ResourceManager api.

There's a `GetSiteDiagnostics()` but no equivalent Update method. There's very limited samples for this API and even looking through the source code is hard as the comments are all autogenerated seem to restate class/method names.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I Configured the FunctionApp to log to a Log Analytics Workspace with  Azure.ResourceManager in Diagnostic Setting but not able to find reference doc related `GetSiteDiagnostics()`  method.

**Reference**:

I have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) for serverless APIs Functions , API Management integration reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/openapi-apim-integrate-visual-studio)  and  Application Insights log  reference  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights).

```
     
       TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            configuration.InstrumentationKey = "your Instrumentation Key";
            TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Hello trigger");
            
telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Enter Trigger name in the request body");
                    telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Hello trigger"+name);
            
            log.LogInformation("My app logs here.");
          
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
```

[image]

- Configured [Azure Diagnostic Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) in azure portal.

[image]

[image]

**Output**  :

[image]

- The Log of Azure Function.

[image]

- Log of a Log Analytics Workspace in Diagnostic Setting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @Sampath but I was after a way to do this with the Azure.ResourceManager API.

Comment: Hello, @RichardAplin used this [packages](https://i.imgur.com/yEjR1tP.png) and I will look into API.

Comment: Unfortunately those packages are deprecated so trying to use the replacement API.

Comment: ok,I will look into API

Comment: Hello,@RichardAplin for serverless APIs in Visual Studio using Azure Functions and API Management integration [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/openapi-apim-integrate-visual-studio) and [log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights)